# Android threading executorService do's and dont's

Tags: java, android, executorservice

Is it a bad practice to maintain a :

```
public static final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

in a singleton class and perform all multi-threading operations using this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static declaration is not, in itself, bad practice.  In fact, `AsyncTask` is implemented in almost exactly that way.

Singletons, on the other hand, often suggest bad practice...

Comment: I was checking out the async-task code.
public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
= new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);

Why have they not simply used a cachedThreadPool ?

Comment: that is why `AsyncTask` nobody uses in real projects :)

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish elaborate please, but I agree for every little threading need creating an async task seems unreasonable

Comment: @Dexter:  The source code for most methods in Executors class are exactly like that.  Creating the ThreadPoolExecutor directly gives you a little more control.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newCachedThreadPool%28%29

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish but if I have to immediately update the UI, using and async-task makes more sense

Comment: AsyncTasks are just small task that get queued on the Executor.  You will be doing exactly the same thing if you use your own Executor.  AsyncTasks are used frequently in real projects.  It's just important to understand how their lifecycle interacts with Activity and Application lifecycles.